# Converting object of class function into function

Tags: r, function, closures

In R, assume an object of type 'closure' called `my_object` that contains both a likelihood function and the associated parameters.

Assume further that I would now like to extract specifically the likelihood function from said object and pass it on to a different R command, which needs a likelihood function as its first argument. I can extract said function via command `unenclose` in library `pryr`.

```
> library(pryr)
> lik_func = unenclose(my_object)
> lik_func
function (pars, condition.surv = TRUE, root = ROOT.OBS, root.p = NULL, 
    intermediates = FALSE) 
{ #function_specifics_here# }
<environment: namespace:diversitree>
```

However, what I apparently extract is just an *object of class 'function'*, and not the likelihood function itself, as the next R command complains that it does not actually receive a function, but an object:

```
> asr.marginal(lik=lik_func, pars=my_pars)
Error in UseMethod("make.asr.marginal") : 
  no applicable method for 'make.asr.marginal' applied to an object of class "function"
```

How do I convert this *object of class 'function'* into a plain *function*, assuming such a distinction actually exists?

Note: I am uncertain if or why a distinction between an *object of class 'function'* and a plain *function* actually exists. Maybe someone answering this question could share some light on this too.

Comment: As you speculated, functions *are* objects in R. Furthermore, `unenclose` doesn’t extract a function from a closure (because a closure *is a function*). It just replaces its closure variables by constants. And as such there’s no need to use `unenclose` here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for your answer. Yes, it appears that I was under some misconception and saw a difference where there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Objects of class `"function"`” are, generally<sup>1</sup>, functions. In particular, they are objects of type `"closure"` and class `"function"`.

Using `pryr::unenclose` doesn’t have any useful effect here. Its only effect is to take a function and replace all references to objects in an enclosing environment with their value. So if I have, say:

```
x = 1
f = function () x
```

… then `unenclose(f)` will yield:

```
function () 1
```

This doesn’t make `f` any more or less of a function.

Your error message seems to be fundamentally unrelated to that. Instead, `asr.marginal` specifically expects a *likelihood function*, which apparently needs to be created by one of the `make.*` functions in the package. A likelihood function in the context of ‹diversitree› is a function of class `"dtlik"`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The exception is if you are prone to shenanigans:

```
x = 42
class(x) = "function"
```

Now `x` has class function but obviously isn’t a function.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation!